# Python 3 list.pop() vs slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Given that:

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

What is the difference between `l.pop(0)` and `l = l[1:]` if we only consider final state of `l`?

It seems to me that contents of `l` should be the same, no matter which option I choose and simple tests seem to show the same, but I have a piece of code which behaves differently based on which operation I use.

I'm using Python 3.6.7 from Anaconda.

EDIT: Code example:

```py
forward = range(10)
backward = forward[::-1]

parts = []
f_p = []
b_p = []
for f, b in zip(forward, backward):
    if len(f_p) == 3:
        parts.append((f_p, b_p))
        f_p = f_p[1:] # f_p.pop(0)
        b_p = b_p[1:] # b_p.pop(0)
    f_p.append(f)
    b_p.append(b)
print(parts)
```

Why are results different?

P.S. I'm aware that `pop()` returns the element, but I'm currently only concerned with the list itself.

Comment: `l.pop` modifies the list, whereas `l[1:]` returns a new list which you happen to be assigning to the same variable.

Comment: "I have a piece of code which behaves differently based on which operation I use"... What is that code?

Comment: Are you sure you read the documentation of [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)? `s.pop([i])` retrieves the item at `i` and also removes it from `s`

Comment: Another thing: scope. 
pop modifies the list in place. If you use pop in a function on a list that has been passed as argument, it will modify the original list. Your second operation would create a local copy of that.

Comment: These two operations also have different [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). What is the different behavior of the code, and could it be related to this fact?

Comment: @hyperTrashPanda isn't the time complexity the same? but slicing uses more memory since the list is copied

Comment: With your example it becomes clear, your modifying the appended list with `f_p.pop(0)` but not with the assignment

Comment: @khelwood Ok, should the contents and their order in the lists be different?

Comment: Different in the sense that replacing one list with another list is not the same thing as modifying the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is one is call by value and other is call by reference.
pop effects the original list whereas slicing doesn't until you explicitly makes it to

```
def test_pop(ls):
    return ls.pop(0)
def test_slice(ls):
    return ls[1:]

l = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(l) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
test_slice(l)
print(l) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] doesn't effect the original list
test_pop(l)
print(l) #[2, 3, 4, 5] effects the original list
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just try to print results, you will saw the results:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
print (l.pop(0)) # 1: The method returns the removed item
print (l) # [2, 3, 4, 5] # list after removing item
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
print (l[1:]) # [2, 3, 4, 5] # new list with starting integer where the slicing of the object starts
```

`l.pop(0)` : The pop() method removes the item at the given index from the list. The method also returns the removed item, in your case returns 1, how you can see if you print list afret using pop() your list doesn't contain thet element anymore

`l[1:]` : The slice() constructor creates a slice object representing the set of indices specified by range(start, stop, step), in your case you got new list with starting integer where the slicing of the object starts

Comment: The contents of both lists and their order is the same in both cases, which is what I stated in my question. My question: what is different between these lists?